# Absolute Image Paths in Gatsby JSON

Tags: javascript, json, image, gatsby, sharp

I am using `gatsby-transformer-json` to query JSON files in Gatsby. There are image URLs within the JSON file, however they are absolute file paths and Gatsby only transforms relative paths into image nodes.

My JSON:

```
{
  "defaultImage": "images/defaultImage.jpg"
}
```

My query:

```
metadataJson {
  defaultImage {
    childImagageSharp {
      fixed(width: 3200, height: 2133) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However this fails with an error because Gatsby is encountering the absolute path and because it isn't relative, it doesn't transform it to a Sharp image node.

If it was a Markdown file I could transform the path myself and save it to the Markdown node's `fields` object. However that option isn't available to me with `gatsby-transformer-json`.

**How can I transform the absolute path in a JSON file so that Gatsby will replace the path with a Sharp image node?**

Comment: Have you solved it somehow? Will you mind sharing your solution? I have exactly the same struggle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `createNodeField` on any type of nodes, not just markdown remark.

If you set up `gatsby-config.js` like the following:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/meta`, <-- folder name is used to create node type name, i.e `MetaJson`
    name: `meta`, <-- doesn't affect json node's type name
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-json`,
```

You can then transform them in `gatsby-node.js` just like how you would do it with MarkdownRemark node.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MetaJson`) {
    const relativePath = ...

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `foo`,
      value: relativePath,
    })
  }
}
```

You can also pass in [additional options](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/#configuration-options) into `gatsby-transformer-json` to have more fine grain control of the json nodes' internal type name.

---

And just like with markdown transformed by `gatsby-transformer-remark`, jsons transformed by `gatsby-transformer-json` also attach a child node onto its parent File node:

```
{
  file( sourceInstanceName: { eq: "meta" } ) {
    dir
    childMetaJson {
      fields {
        foo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach looks correct, but no matter what I do, I cannot get Gatsby to transform the path into a File node, even if I use the path of another frontmatter image that is correctly transformed. It just ignores the value and leaves it as a string.

Comment: @Undistraction It's hard to tell without more context, but I think the problem could be that if gatsby found a node whose field didn't link to a file, it'll assume the type of that field for all other nodes (of the same node type). Is your project happened to be open source? Or could you replicate the problem in a small repo?